# Robolectric not finding my Manifest failing all my tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-testing, robolectric

When i try run my tests with roboelectric i get this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml not found or not a file; it should point to your project's AndroidManifest.xml
```

I have my test class annotated like this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@org.robolectric.annotation.Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*"})
@PrepareForTest({Realm.class})
public class DataJUnitTest{}
```

So all my Tests are failing because of this exception any help please, thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Robolectric do you use?

Comment: In case you are using Linux or Mac see solution here in part "Note for Linux and Mac Users": http://robolectric.org/getting-started/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i was using robolectric version 3.0, once i updated to 3.2.2 everything worked out